# What is the pattern in this sequence of integers

Tags: prime-numbers

Hey guys, I recently stumbled across this interesting sequence:

1, 3, 5, 11, 17, 39, 65, 139, 261, 531, 1025, 2095, 4097, 8259, 16405, 32907, 65537, 131367, 262145 ...

Any ideas?  The sequence appears to somewhat resemble the binary sequence.

Comment: After 262145, it seems to take constantly the value 14. Very strange. Very strange indeed.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, where did you obtain this result?

Comment: @Mariano means that there's no well defined way of extending a finite sequence of numbers to an infinite sequence. Of course, some extensions are "better" than others.

Comment: You are absolutely right! In retrospect, I have proposed a rather impossible task with my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try this: http://oeis.org/A034729

$$ a(n) = \sum_{k, k|n } 2^{(k-1)}$$

In Mathematica syntax this is (see [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BSum%5B2%5E%28k-1%29,%7Bk,Divisors%5Bn%5D%7D%5D,%7Bn,1,20%7D%5D))

```
 Sum[2^(k - 1), {k, Divisors[n]}]
```

Comment: @abc123 Not a problem. The OEIS is a very handy resource.